# a for loop that puts the user inputted number into a text field. It doesn't print out to the field or System.out.println

Tags: java, netbeans

I am not sure if the code works as it does not print in to the text field. My code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int startNum = 0, endNum = 0, difference;
    difference = endNum - startNum;

    startNum = Integer.parseInt(startInput.getText());
    endNum = Integer.parseInt(endInput.getText());

    if(difference > 1)
    {
        for (int i = startNum; i <= endNum; i++)
        {


            output.setText(Integer.toString(i));

        }  
    }
    else if(difference < 1)
    {
        for (int i = startNum; i >= endNum; i--)
        {

            output.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: `difference = endNum - startNum;` before parsing those values from input. I voted to close this question as a simple typographic

Comment: In case it isn't clear, what @Danh is saying is that you are calculating the difference before you set startNum and endNum, so difference will always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
 int startNum = 0, endNum = 0, difference;
    difference = endNum - startNum;//<--WRONG, it should be after the next two lines. Because you are setting startNum and endNum values to zero and you are calculating the difference.

    startNum = Integer.parseInt(startInput.getText());
    endNum = Integer.parseInt(endInput.getText());// But after taking the input you are not calculating the difference
```

Correct Code:

```
 int startNum = 0, endNum = 0, difference;

    startNum = Integer.parseInt(startInput.getText());
    endNum = Integer.parseInt(endInput.getText());
   difference = endNum - startNum;//<--HERE, this is where it should be
```

Makes sense?